# Is it possible to develop an Android Service that sees exactly which view is open by other apps?

Tags: java, android, service, accessibilityservice

For a current project, I have a need for an Android service that would be able to tell the content, and view that another app has open -- following a user action(clicking something in the notifications bar, perhaps)

The Service needs to be able to:

1. Accept a user action
2. Recognise which view the user is in
3. Get the textual content of that view

The only way I can currently see to do this is using an AccessibilityService -- Are those still allowed by Google for non-accessibility uses and is there an alternative?

Comment: `Are those still allowed by Google` Please avoid such question with regards to policy otherwise your question will be marked as off-topic so only ask programming questions.

Comment: No, for good reason-  the ability of malware to manipulate that with banking apps and other private data is way too high.  An accessibility service is the closest you can come, and it won't tell you all that much.

Comment: The most important thing I need to know is where, for example which YouTube video is playing in the app - and the user interaction required for collection reduces the risk of too much data being exposed

Answer (score 0):

I dont think a service has sufficient permissions to do this(non rooted Android device.) However you can take a look at screen overlays, They might help you with what you need

Comment: That enables you to overlay something over the content, but can you point anywhere where it mentions how to access views under it? Or any content under it

Comment: Take a look at this app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opensource.goiv&hl=en_IN. It does the same functions you want i think